# Pythonnet primavera DLL

Tags: python

Estou a tentar usar a biblioteca pythonnet para aceder as dll do primavera, até agora consegui abrir as dll e usar algumas das funções básicas da mesma, mas agora estou preso ao tentar utilizar o método AbreEmpresaTrabalho.

```
import clr

clr.AddReference(r'dll\SG900\Interop.ErpBS900')
from Interop.ErpBS900 import ErpBS
motor = ErpBS
motor().AbreEmpresaTrabalho("2", "TESTE", "Primavera", "Primavera.123")

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: REGISTO: Entrada HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\PRIMAVERA\SGS900\DEFAULT\ADM não encontrada.
   em Interop.ErpBS900.ErpBSClass.AbreEmpresaTrabalho(EnumTipoPlataforma& enuTipoPlataforma, String& strCodEmp, String& strUtilizador, String& strPassword, StdBETransaccao& objTrans, String& strInstancia, Boolean& blnModoPrimario)
```

Esta última linha da me erro de regedit penso eu, mas não sei como resolver.

Comment: Não conheço, mas se me permite um palpite: Não existe uma chave no registro do Windows, parecendo que o software não está instalado.

Comment: Olá, foi o que pensei tambem mas tenho o primavera instalado na maquina onde estou a desenvolver, no entanto no regedit as chaves nao estao guardadas na mesma diretoria. Tentei copiar a estrutura mas de nada serviu. eu tenho registado no regedit da seguinte forma:
Computer\HKEY_LOCA_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Primavera|SGP900
e quando tento utilizar uma funcao da dll ele pede me um caminho diferente
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\PRIMAVERA\SGS900\DEFAULT\ADM

Comment: Está rodando como administrador?

Comment: Olá, sim atéisso ja tentei,. Tentei outra coisa, instalei o primavera numa mauqina com windows 32 bits, criei as entradas de regedit a mao e consegui pasar desse erro, agora já tenho outro tipo de erro e nao faço ideia do que possa ser.

`IndexError: tuple assignment index out of range
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: <bound method 'AbreEmpresaTrabalho'> returned a result with an error set`